# dockerized shiny app does not work when loading data outside of container

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I have a simple shiny app which load data from `data` folder and generate an interactive plot. I dockerized my shiny app. I put the `data` folder within the container. The dockerized app can be deployed successfully on my localhost.
Here is my `global.r` file:

```
library(shiny) 
library(dplyr)
df = readRDS('./data/mydata.rds')
```

Eventually I need the shiny app to load data from an outside folder. So I changed my `global.r` file like this:

```
library(shiny) 
library(dplyr)
df = readRDS('c:/user/document/data/mydata.rds')
```

Here I want the app to load data from one of the folders on my local drive.`c:/user/document/data/`. The app runs perfectly by itself. But after I dockerized it and tried to run the docker image on localhost. It failed!

I seems that the app cannot connect to folder outside of the docker container?  I'm new with docker. I'm confused....

Does anyone know how I can make shiny app connect and load data from a folder outside of docker container? Either from a folder on local drive or a sharepoint folder or ....? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Docker containers as it is cannot access data from outside. You need to use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for that. A volume basically acts as a common storage for both your host and the container. So, while running your docker container you need to specify the host path and container path like this `docker run -v c:/username/document/data:c:/username/document/data image-name`
Also, I am assuming that you are trying to run a Windows container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Could you explain a little bit more about host path and container path? Say, my folder that contains dockerfile and app is `c:/username/shinyapp` and my external datafolder is `c:/username/document/data`. App is on localhost.    How to specify `volume`?  @Praveen Rewar

Comment: I have updated the docker run command in my answer. Also, I am assuming that you are on windows and you are using windows container.

Comment: sorry, I did not see any update on your answer. Could you update that with the example folder I provided? Huge thanks!  @Praveen Rewar

Comment: Hey I am really sorry I am not sure how it didn't get updated 

Comment: Sorry, is it right? There is non path like `C:/username/data`  Which one should be the host path? which one should be container path? @Praveen Rewar

Comment: Sorry, I am on phone, so missed the document part

Comment: both host and container path are my data folder path?  Could you explain a little bit more?    my folder that contains dockerfile and app is `c:/username/shinyapp` and my external datafolder is `c:/username/document/data`  @Praveen Rewar

Comment: Okay, let's say that in the app, you have provided the location of that data folder as `c:/username/document/data`. Now when you run the container the app would look for the data directory in the same location. That's why the hosts data directory should be  in sync with the container data directory. Of course you can provide a different path for the container but then you will have to use the same in the app (`df = readRDS...`).